# Is it possible to choose a layout file to be put in an inner layout of a main layout depending on a button press?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

Sorry for the confusing question, the example might clear things up. I am trying to set an inner layout to some other layout file. For simplicity, I made these all linear layouts, but in general I'd prefer it to be any type of layout. Given main_layout.xml, can I set the inner LinearLayout (chooseLayout) to layout_1.xml or layout_2.xml depending on a button press?

Example:

layout_1.xml - small layout 1

layout_2.xml - small layout 2

main_layout.xml - our main layout to be displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chooseLayout"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a single layout file to implement the effect you want.

Simply give the "subview" that you want to hide the `android:visibility` value of "gone", and give the subview you want to be visible the `android:visibility` value of "visible".

For example, if you wanted `subView1` to display, and `subView2` to be hidden by default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/subView1"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/subView2"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your code, you can call a method like the following to swap the visibility of the 2 subviews. I assume that there are instance variables `subView1` and `subView2` for the 2 subviews.

```
private void swapSubviewVisibility(View subviewToDisplay) {
    View subviewToHide = (subviewToDisplay == subView1 ? subView2 : subView1);
    subviewToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    subviewToDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like creating views programmatically using inflater.
Here is working code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
public static final int LAYOUT_FIRST = 1;
public static final int LAYOUT_SECOND = 2;

LinearLayout container;
Button b1, b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);

}
private void setInnerLayout(int which){
    int resId = 0;
    switch (which){
        case LAYOUT_FIRST: resId = R.layout.layout1; break;
        case LAYOUT_SECOND: resId = R.layout.layout2; break;
    }
    if (resId!=0){
        container.removeAllViews();
        container.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(resId, container, false));
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1: setInnerLayout(LAYOUT_FIRST); break;
        case R.id.button2: setInnerLayout(LAYOUT_SECOND); break;
    }
}
```

}

And for your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Button1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the link to complete code on github: [REPO](https://github.com/mrnmilutinovic/stackoverflow-answer1)